# Ruby array creation, Array.new vs []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What's the difference between these two statements? I use them in my rails app and to me it looks like they do the same thing

```
array_a = Array.new
array_b = []
```

Comment: To clear/reset array without creating a new object, use `array.clear` to achieve `#=> [ ]`

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Those two statements are functionally identical. `Array.new` however can take arguments and a block:

```
Array.new # => []
Array.new(2) # => [nil,nil]
Array.new(5,"A") # =>["A","A","A","A","A"]

a = Array.new(2,Hash.new)
a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
a # => [{"cat"=>"feline"},{"cat"=>"feline"}]
a[1]['cat'] = 'Felix'
a # => [{"cat"=>"Felix"},{"cat"=>"Felix"}]

a = Array.new(2){Hash.new} # Multiple instances
a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
a # =>[{"cat"=>"feline"},{}]
squares = Array.new(5){|i|i*i}
squares # => [0,1,4,9,16]

copy = Array.new(squares) # initialized by copying
squares[5] = 25
squares # => [0,1,4,9,16,25]
copy # => [0,1,4,9,16]
```

Note: the above examples taken from [Programming Ruby 1.9](http://pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9)

Comment: `Array.new(count, object)` producing an array of the same object is a gotcha that means I avoid using that approach.

Comment: @Andrew: not exactly in line with the "principle of least surprise", is it?

Comment: lucky that i found your answer within a minute of my doubt.

Answer (score 10):

`[]` is a shortcut to the Array class's singleton method `[]` which in turn creates a new Array in just the same way as `Array.new`, so you could probably say 'they are the same' without worrying too much.

Note that each call to `[]` in irb creates a new Array:

```
>> [].object_id
=> 2148067340
>> [].object_id
=> 2149414040
```

From [Ruby's C code](http://ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/array_8c-source.html):

```
rb_define_singleton_method(rb_cArray, "[]", rb_ary_s_create, -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Such as `Hash.new` vs `{}`. They are the same. Include speed.

Answer (score 2):

### There is no difference, but...

As others have already answered you

> Those two statements are functionally identical

But there are guidelines to orient when you should use each one (so your code is easier to read). The reason behind that is:

> Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.

from:
https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#literal-array-hash

> Prefer literal array and hash creation notation (unless you need to pass parameters to their constructors, that is).

So if you are creating an empty array `[]` is the best option, but if you need to create your array with a set of N nil objects, than `Array.new(N)` is what you should write.

Answer (score 1):

There is fundamentally no difference