# In Ruby, why does Array.new(size, object) create an array consisting of multiple references to the same object?

Tags: ruby, arrays

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601652/ruby-array-creation-array-new-vs/4601727#4601727), `Array.new(size, object)` creates an array with `size` references to the same `object`.

```
hash = Hash.new
a = Array.new(2, hash)
a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
a # => [{"cat"=>"feline"},{"cat"=>"feline"}]
a[1]['cat'] = 'Felix'
a # => [{"cat"=>"Felix"},{"cat"=>"Felix"}]
```

Why does Ruby do this, rather than doing a `dup` or `clone` of `object`?

Answer (score 9):

Because that's what [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000209) says it does. Note that `Hash.new` is only being called once, so of course there's only one `Hash`

If you want to create a new object for every element in the array, pass a block to the `Array.new` method, and that block will be called for each new element:

```
>> a = Array.new(2) { Hash.new }
=> [{}, {}]
>> a[0]['cat'] = 'feline'
=> "feline"
>> a
=> [{"cat"=>"feline"}, {}]
>> a[1]['cat'] = 'Felix'
=> "Felix"
>> a
=> [{"cat"=>"feline"}, {"cat"=>"Felix"}]
```

Comment: "Because that's what the documentation says it does." - I was hoping to pop the why stack a little further than that.

Comment: Popping the why stack: because when you pass in an object to be used to pre-populate the array, the array will be pre-populated with that object.

Comment: @Justice: Were you being serious or sarcastic with that comment?

Comment: Both. Serious, because the second parameter to `Array.new` is indeed the parameter used to pre-populate the array. Sarcastic, because Gareth said as much in his answer, and I am simply restating what he said.

Comment: `Array.new(size, 0)` zero-fills a new array.

Comment: @Justice: Under what circumstances would you want to create an array that consists entirely of references to the same mutable object? (Referring to `Array.new(size, hash)`, not to `Array.new(size, 0)`)

Comment: I would flip that around and say, why would you want Ruby to implicitly create copies of an arbitrary object (which might be an expensive operation), when you also have a mechanism to carry out the duplication yourself?

Comment: Because the existing behaviour [seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601652/ruby-array-creation-array-new-vs/4601727#4601727) to violate "Principle of least surprise"

Answer (score 2):

For certain classes that can't be modified in-place (like `Fixnum`s) the `Array.new(X, object)` form works as expected and is probably more efficient (it just calls `memfill` instead of `rb_ary_store` and `yield`ing to the block):

For more complicated objects you always have the block form (e.g. `Array.new(5) { Hash.new }`).

**Edit*:* Modified according to the comments. Sorry for the stupid example, I was tired when I wrote that.

Comment: You're replacing c[1] with a new object, rather than modifying it.

Comment: >> c[1] << "h"; c #=> ["ah", "ah", "ah", "ah", "ah"]

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that answer right before going to bed, you are right of course. The rest should still be true too.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this answer, very short and simple solution

```
c_hash = Hash.new
["a","b","c","d","e","f"].each do |o|
  tmp = Hash.new
  [1,2,3].map {|r| tmp[r] = Array.new}
  c_hash[o] = tmp
end
c_hash['a'][1] << 10
p c_hash
```

Comment: But the question is **why** all indexes  reference the same object

Comment: References in Ruby (and in almost every other programming language) point to a single object in memory. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46330723/5793994

The reference never changed. The original reference is and will always in this case be the original r_hash.

The reference was never moved away form that hash.

This is just classic objects. :)

Comment: You didn't understand. Your answer should contain answer to the asked question. Question is **why** but you answer **how** to avoid it. Don't explain in comments, [edit] your answer