# Why doesn't terse way of defining new hashes in Ruby work (they all refer to same object)

Tags: ruby, hash, initialization

I need to establish a number of Hashes, and I didn't want to list one per line, like this

```
a = Hash.new
b = Hash.new
```

I also new that apart from for Fixnums, I could not do this

```
a = b = Hash.new
```

because both a and b would reference the same object. What I could to is this

```
a, b, = Hash.new, Hash.new
```

if I had a bunch it seemed like I could also do this

```
a, b = [Hash.new] * 2
```

this works for strings, but for Hashes, they still all reference the same object, despite the fact that

```
[Hash.new, Hash.new] == [Hash.new] * 2
```

and the former works.

See the code sample below, the only error message triggered is "multiplication hash broken". Just curious why this is.

```
a, b, c = [String.new] * 3
a = "hi"
puts "string broken" unless b == ""

puts "not equivalent" unless [Hash.new, Hash.new, Hash.new] == [Hash.new] * 3

a, b, c = [Hash.new, Hash.new, Hash.new]
a['hi'] = :test
puts "normal hash broken" unless b == {}

a, b, c = [Hash.new] * 3
a['hi'] = :test
puts "multiplication hash broken" unless b == {}
```

Comment: I've wondered about [why it's done this way (except with Arrays) as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642395/in-ruby-why-does-array-newsize-object-create-an-array-consisting-of-multiple)

Comment: What's wrong with `a, b, c = { 'hi' => :test }, {}, {}` or even just `a = { 'hi' => :test}; b = {}; c = {}`? [Note: SO doesn't allow line breaks in comments; I'm suggesting to use three lines, not semicolons.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In answer to the original question, an easy way to initialize multiple copies would be to use the `Array.new(size) {|index| block }` variant of [Array.new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000209)

```
a, b = Array.new(2) { Hash.new }
a, b, c = Array.new(3) { Hash.new }
# ... and so on
```

On a side note, in addition to the assignment mix-up, the other seeming issue with the original is that it appears you might be making the mistake that `==` is comparing object references of `Hash` and `String`.  Just to be clear, it doesn't.

```
# Hashes are considered equivalent if they have the same keys/values (or none at all)
hash1, hash2 = {}, {}
hash1 == hash1 #=> true
hash1 == hash2 #=> true

# so of course
[Hash.new, Hash.new] == [Hash.new] * 2 #=> true

# however
different_hashes = [Hash.new, Hash.new] 
same_hash_twice  = [Hash.new] * 2
different_hashes == same_hash_twice #=> true
different_hashes.map(&:object_id) == same_hash_twice.map(&:object_id) #=> false
```

Comment: This is great, I've definitively learnt a lot of Ruby from this thread. Did not know about the Array.new (size) {|index| block} version of Array.new, and was also not clear about comparing Hashes. Thanks to both numbers1311407 and Dan Tao!

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is this. `[String.new] * 3` does *not* create three `String` objects. It creates *one*, and creates a 3-element array where each element points to that same object.

The reason you don't see "string broken" is that you have **assigned** `a` to a new value. So after the line `a = "hi"`, `a` refers to a new `String` object ("hi") while `b` and `c` still refer to the same original object ("").

The same occurs with `[Hash.new] * 3`; but this time you don't re-assign any variables. Rather, you *modify* the one `Hash` object by adding the key/value `[hi, :test]` (via `a['hi'] = :test`). In this step you've modified the one object referred to by `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Here's a contrived code example to make this more concrete:

```
class Thing
  attr_accessor :value
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
  end
end

# a, b, and c all refer to the same Thing object
a, b, c = [Thing.new(0)] * 3

# Here we *modify* that object
a.value = 5

# Verify b refers to the same object as a -- outputs "5"
puts b.value

# Now *assign* a to a NEW Thing object
a = Thing.new(10)

# Verify a and b now refer to different objects -- outputs "10, 5"
puts "#{a.value}, #{b.value}"
```

Does that make sense?

---

**Update**: I'm no Ruby guru, so there might be a more common-sense way to do this. But if you wanted to be able to use multiplication-like syntax to initialize an array with a bunch of different objects, you might consider this approach: create an array of *lambdas*, then call all of them using `map`.

Here's what I mean:

```
def call_all(lambdas)
  lambdas.map{ |f| f.call }
end

a, b, c = call_all([lambda{Hash.new}] * 3)
```

You can verify that this approach works pretty easily:

```
x, y, z = call_all([lambda{rand(100)}] * 3)

# This should output 3 random (probably different) numbers
puts "#{x}, #{y}, #{z}"
```

---

**Update 2**: I like [numbers1311407's approach using `Array#new`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178150/numbers1311407) a lot better.

Comment: I think you nailed his misunderstanding in paragraph 2. To put it even more simply, just change line 2 in the original example to `a << 'hi'` which would append to it instead of replacing it, and the test on line 3 will fail as expected.

Comment: Cool, that perfectly explains it. Silly mistake about the string. So there is no more elegant way of multiple assignment than a,b = Hash.new, Hash.new then? Thanks - not a big issue, but I learnt something about Ruby today.