# Pushing a string into an array within an array yields unexpected result

Tags: ruby

I have an array in Ruby that consists of 5 empty arrays. I am trying to use the `<<` operator to push a string into the first array, but the result is that the string gets pushed into ALL of the arrays. Please help me understand this.

The expected output is:

```
# => [["car"], [], [], [], []]
```

but instead I get:

```
# => [["car"], ["car"], ["car"], ["car"], ["car"]]
```

irb dump:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > output = Array.new(5, [])
 => [[], [], [], [], []] 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > output.inspect
 => "[[], [], [], [], []]" 
1.9.3-p194 :003 > output[0].inspect
 => "[]" 
1.9.3-p194 :004 > output[0] << "car"
 => ["car"] 
1.9.3-p194 :005 > output.inspect
 => "[[\"car\"], [\"car\"], [\"car\"], [\"car\"], [\"car\"]]"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't terse way of defining new hashes in Ruby work (they all refer to same object)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540084/why-doesnt-terse-way-of-defining-new-hashes-in-ruby-work-they-all-refer-to-sam)

Comment: Thanks all!   This was REALLY stumping me.  And now I learned a new method: object_id

Comment: Can anyone help me understand why this is happening, so I can understand Ruby better?

Comment: You are creating five instances of the same `[]` array, which is why you see duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're all the same object:

```
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :001 > output = Array.new(5, [])
 => [[], [], [], [], []] 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :002 > output[0]
 => [] 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :003 > output[0].object_id
 => 2219989240 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :004 > output[1].object_id
 => 2219989240 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :005 > output[2].object_id
 => 2219989240 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :006 > output[3].object_id
 => 2219989240 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :007 > output[4].object_id
 => 2219989240 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :008 >
```

Try this:

```
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :008 > output = []
 => [] 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :009 > 5.times{output << []}
 => 5
```

Answer (score 5):

They all have the same object id, as pointed out by Pedro Nascimento, if the arrays are initialized in that manner.  You can get around this by using a [similar syntax](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-new) to create your nested arrays:

```
irb(main):047:0> output = Array.new(5) {[]}
=> [[], [], [], [], []]
irb(main):048:0> output.each {|i| puts i.object_id}
10941700
10941680
10941660
10941640
10941620
```

So your append to `output[0]` will work as expected:

```
irb(main):049:0> output[0] << "cat"
=> ["cat"]
irb(main):050:0> output
=> [["cat"], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
output = Array.new(5, [])
```

is trying to create only one copy of the object,

So

```
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :003 > output[0].object_id
 => 2219989240 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :004 > output[1].object_id
 => 2219989240 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :005 > output[2].object_id
 => 2219989240 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :006 > output[3].object_id
 => 2219989240 
ree-1.8.7-2012.02 :007 > output[4].object_id
 => 2219989240
```

If you want to create multiple copies of object, use this

```
     output = Array.new(5) {[]}    #=> [[], [], [], [], []]
```

The code

```
 output.each {|i| puts i.object_id}
```

will show you

```
1.9.3-p194 :005 >  output.each {|i| puts i.object_id}
13417360
13417340
13417320
13417300
13417280
 => [[], [], [], [], []]
```