# Array of Arrays in ruby, passed by reference

Tags: ruby, arrays, reference

I'm trying to create a 5x5 matrix in Ruby filled with zeroes. The code I used was:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :014 > a = Array.new(5, Array.new(5, 0))
 => [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

However, the newly created arrays inside are not separate objects, but a reference to one. So when I try to do the following: `a[2][2] = 1` I get:

```
=> [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Which is obviously not what I want. Checking objects ids confirms it:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :020 > a.collect {|z| z.__id__}.uniq
 => [70253724580020]
```

My questions is: is it a bug or feature? :) And how should I create array of arrays properly?

Comment: I asked why it does it this way, but didn't get an answer that satisfied me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642395/in-ruby-why-does-array-newsize-object-create-an-array-consisting-of-multiple

Answer (score 9):

> I'm trying to create a 5x5 matrix in Ruby filled with zeroes. The code I used was:

As others have pointed out, this is how arrays are supposed to work. Instead, you should use the block initializer:

```
a = Array.new(5) { Array.new(5, 0) }
```

In addition, however, if you're making a matrix, **consider using the Matrix class in the standard library**:

```
require 'matrix'
 # => true 

m = Matrix.build(5, 5) { 0 }
 # => Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 #           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 #           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 #           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 #           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] 

m.determinant
 # => 0
```

Answer (score 6):

Actually it is a [feature](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-new).

> [...] it is created with *size* copies of *obj* (that is, *size* references
>   to the same *obj*) [...]

To create distinct arrays you can use e.g.

```
a = Array.new(5){Array.new(5, 0)}
```

or

```
a = (1..5).map{Array.new(5, 0)}
```

Comment: +1 for backing up your assertion with an authoritative reference.