# Blank array behaving strangely when filling it with values depending on how it was created (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I've got an array of arrays where it's filled iteratively, but for some reason, it seems like how it was defined is changing its behaviour even when its result is equal to that of the other method. So here's the code:

```
@height = 5
@nums = (1..60).to_a

@grid = []

@height.times do # Method one for making the grid
  @grid << []
end

print @grid, "\n" # Print the grid, shows [[], [], [], [], []] as expected

@grid2 = Array.new(@height, []) # Cleaner way of making the grid

print @grid2, "\n" # Print the grid, shows [[], [], [], [], []] as expected

print @grid2 == @grid, "\n" # Are they equal? returns true as expected

@grid = @grid2 # Commenting out this line changes the behavior of the output

@nums.length.times do |n|         # Fill the grid with our numbers
  @grid[n % @height] << @nums[n]
end

@grid.each do |i|   # Display the grid
  print i, "\n"
end
```

Comment: Note that when using an optional object in creating `@grid2`, all elements will reference _the same object_.  See [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642395/in-ruby-why-does-array-newsize-object-create-an-array-consisting-of-multiple).

Comment: @red_menace, thanks, that's exactly what the problem was!

Comment: Consider posting an answer to get this closed out

Comment: Specifically for your case, ` Array.new(@height, [])` should be ` Array.new(@height) { [] }`.