# Changing one array in an array of arrays changes them all; why?

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
a = Array.new(3,[])
a[1][0] = 5
a => [[5], [5], [5]]
```

I thought this doesn't make sense!
isn't it should a => [[], [5], []]
or this's sort of Ruby's feature ?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642395/in-ruby-why-does-array-newsize-object-create-an-array-consisting-of-multiple and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601652/ruby-array-creation-array-new-vs/4601727#4601727

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
a = Array.new(3){ [] }
```

With your code the same object is used for the value of each entry; once you mutate one of the references you see all others change. With the above you instead invoke the block each time a new value is needed, which returns a new array *each time*.

---

*This is similar in nature to the new user question about why the following does not work as expected:*

```
str.gsub /(<([a-z]+)>/, "-->#{$1}<--"
```

*In the above, string interpolation occurs before the `gsub` method is ever called, so it cannot use the then-current value of `$1` in your string. Similarly, in your question you create an object and pass it to `Array.new` **before** Ruby starts creating array slots. Yes, the runtime **could** call `dup` on the item by default…but that would be potentially disastrous and slow. Hence you get the block form to determine on your own how to create the initial values.*

Comment: Slight nitpick: "once you mutate one of the instances you mutate them all" – Actually, there is only *one* instance, that's precisely the problem!