# Odd Ruby Behaviour

Tags: ruby

Consider the following Ruby code:

```
a = ["x"] * 3 # or a = Array.new(3, "x")

a[0].insert(0, "a")
a.each {|i| puts i}
```

I would expect the output to be ax, x, x (on new lines of course).  However, with Ruby 1.9.1 the output is ax, ax, ax.  What's going on?  I've narrowed the problem down to the way the array `a` is defined.  If I explicitly write out

```
a = ["x", "x", "x"]
```

then the code works as expected, but either version in the original code gives me this unexpected behaviour.  It appears that the */initializer means the copies are actually references to the same copy of the string "x".  However, if instead of the insert command I write

```
a[0] = "a" + a[0]
```

Then I get the desired output.  Is this a bug, or is there some feature at work which I'm not understanding?

Comment: Related but not identical: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835030/changing-one-array-in-an-array-of-arrays-changes-them-all-why?lq=1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation to [Array.new(size=0, obj=nil)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-new):

> ... it is created with *size* copies of *obj* (that is, *size* references to the same *obj*).

and [Array * int](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2A):

> ... returns a new array built by concatenating the *int* copies of `self`

So in both of the forms you're surprised by, you end up with three references to the same `"x"` object, just as you figured out.  I'd say you might argue about the design decision, but it's a documented intentional behavior, not a bug.

The best way I know to get the behavior you want without manually writing the array literal (`["x", "x", "x"]`) is

```
a = Array.new(3) {"x"}
```

Or course, with just three elements, it doesn't much matter, but with anything much bigger, this form comes in handy.

Comment: You can leave off the unused block variable in your last example.

Comment: @MichaelKohl Thanks -- I can't believe I've been missing that detail all these years! (Answer now updated.)

Comment: @DarshanComputing I even read the documentation, and some how missed that.  Thank you!  However, this still leaves me wondering why `a[0]="a" +a[0]` only modifies the first element when initialized as in my first post...

Comment: `a[0] = "a" + a[0]` doesn't modify the string at `a[0]`, it creates a new string (`"a" + a[0]`) and sets `a[0]` to refer to that instead of to the old value.  The value that `a[0]` used to refer to is unharmed, and `a[1]` and `a[2]` happen to still point to that old value.

Answer (score 0):

In short, although "x" is just a literal, it is an object. You use `["x'] * 3` so a is containing 3 same object. You insert 'a' to one of them, they will be all changed.