# Differences between literals and constructors? ([] vs Array.new and {} vs Hash.new)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was curious to know more differences between [] and Array.new and {} and Hash.new

I ran same benchmarks on it and seems like the shorthands are winners

```
require 'benchmark'

many = 500000

Benchmark.bm do |b|
  b.report("[]          \t") {many.times { [].object_id }}
  b.report("Array.new   \t") { many.times { Array.new.object_id }}
  b.report("{}          \t") {many.times { {}.object_id }}
  b.report("Hash.new\t") { many.times { Hash.new.object_id }}
end


                  user     system      total        real
[]            0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.079287)
Array.new     0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.177105)
{}            0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.079467)
Hash.new      0.260000   0.000000   0.260000 (  0.264796)
```

I personally like to use the shorthand one's [] and {} , the code looks so cool and readable.

Any other pointer what is the difference between them? what happens behind scene that make it so better, and suggestions if any when to use which?

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601652/ruby-array-creation-array-new-vs) but was looking to get more info.

cheers.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With Hash.new you can set the default value of the hash for unset keys. This is quite useful if you're doing statistics, because `Hash.new(0)` will let you increment keys without explicitly initializing them.

Answer (score 7):

So for half a million times they all ran "very quickly". I prefer literals in *any* language ([], {}, 0, "", etc.) but the literals can't do everything (see the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-c-new) for the other [constructor forms](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new)). Write clean code, and be consistent: there is no issue here :)

However, **I *suspect* the literals *avoid* a constant lookup and a method call** which results in them being faster, at least in that *particular* implementation .. (someone with more smarts than me could look at the intermediate AST generated to prove/disprove this.)

That is, what if `Hash` resolved to a *custom class* or `Hash.new` was replaced with a *custom method*? Can't do that with `{}`. In addition, the methods have to deal with additional arguments (or blocks) while the literals do not.

Comment: I never thought of this " Hash.new can replaced with a custom method, Can't do that with {}" . nice catch

Answer (score 6):

[Robert already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11802040/676874) the default value of the `Hash.new`

You may also use compley 'default'-values with the block variant of `Hash.new`:

```
x = Hash.new { |hash, key|
  hash[key] = key * 2
}

p x      #-> {}
p x[1]   #-> 2
p x      #-> {1=>2}
```

`Array.new` can also be used to get default values:

```
p Array.new(5, :a)  #-> [:a, :a, :a, :a, :a]
```