# Why monkeypatching Hash.new is not working?

Tags: ruby, hash, monkeypatching

I am monkeypatching Ruby's `Hash` class.

```
class Hash
  alias_method :_initialize, :initialize

  def initialize
     puts 'In my hash class'
     _initialize
  end
end
```

When I do

```
Hash.new
```

it works as expected. But let us say I have a function that takes a `Hash`. Something like,

```
foo 'a' => 'b'
```

In this case my `Hash` class is not used. I'd expect my `Hash` class's `initialize` method to be called. Why is it behaving like this?

Comment: You may find [one of my old answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11801887/differences-between-literals-and-constructors-vs-array-new-and-vs-hash-n/11801991#11801991) useful - if the tentative assertion I post there is indeed correct, then this is a limitation/quirk of the particular Ruby implementation and how hash literals (in whichever form) are implemented

Comment: Why would you do this instead of subclassing Hash?

Comment: @MarkRushakoff I am writing a DSL. Without this, I have to write,

`foo 'key' => 'value'`

With this, I can write,

`foo do {'key' => 'value'}{'key1' => 'value1'} end`

I don't have to keep saying `foo` everywhere.

Comment: @Appu which version of ruby you are using? How did you come to know `In this case my Hash class is not used`?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu I am using 1.9.3. It didn't print the message I put in `initialize`

Answer (score 0):

Because the literal hash won't call the `initialize` method which `Hash.new` will call.

Same as `Hash['a', 'b']` or `Hash['a' => 'b']`

Comment: That's weird. Initialize is the constructor right? So it gets called when any instance of the class is created, right?

Comment: @Appu yes, I am also thinking the same,how an object will be created without initialize :(

Comment: @xdazz, do you know where in the MRI's source code can it be seen?

Comment: No, `initialize` is not the constructor. Ruby doesn't have constructors. `initialize` is a method exactly like any other method. If you don't call it, then it won't get called. Simple as that.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You're 100% wrong - http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/objinitialization.html

Comment: @chintanparikh: No, I'm not. `Class#new` calls `initialize` by default, but `new` is a method like any other, it can be overridden or monkey patched to *not* call `initialize`. `initialize` doesn't magically get called whenever an object is initialized. In fact, it is fairly common to initialize objects without calling `initialize`, e.g. when `clone`ing or `dup`ing objects or when deserializing from `Marshal`, JSON, YAML, XML, etc.