# Inserting values in array inside a nested hash updates multiple records

Tags: ruby

I am trying to insert values to an array in a nested hash as follows:

```
c_hash = {}
r_hash = {}
[1, 2, 3].map{ |r| r_hash[r] = [] }
# => [[], [], []]
r_hash
# => {1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"].map { |o| c_hash[o] = r_hash }
# => [{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, {1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, {1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, {1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, {1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, {1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}]
c_hash
# => {"a"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "b"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "c"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "d"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "e"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "f"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}}
c_hash["a"][1] << 10
c_hash
# => {"a"=>{1=>[10], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "b"=>{1=>[10], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "c"=>{1=>[10], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "d"=>{1=>[10], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "e"=>{1=>[10], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "f"=>{1=>[10], 2=>[], 3=>[]}}
```

But the value `10` is inserted in multiple records. While hardcoding the hash value (`10`), it is inserted only once.

```
c_hash = {"a"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "b"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "c"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "d"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "e"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "f"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}}
c_hash["a"][1] << 10
# => [10]
c_hash
# => {"a"=>{1=>[10], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "b"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "c"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "d"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "e"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}, "f"=>{1=>[], 2=>[], 3=>[]}}
```

Could you please explain why this happens?

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601652/ruby-array-creation-array-new-vs/4601727#4601727

Comment: @webster no need of r_hash, try this, `["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"].map { |o| c_hash[o] = [1, 2, 3].inject({}){ |m, r| m[r] = []; m } }`

Comment: @ray Why tell me? Say it to the OP.

Comment: I had same problem when I used  `Array.new(5,[])`  but solved using `Array.new(5) { Array.new }`